# How to stop Sublime Text 3 from Scrolling opened file tabs automatically on startup

Tags: sublimetext3

When I start sublime text 3, it starts jumping from one file tab to another in a cyclic manner and then stops on the same file. The Sublime text build is 3143. This happens once.

Comment: That is something you probably want to contact the developer about.

Comment: probably you have a package installed that is causing this behavior

Comment: Yes, it was caused by the syncedSidebar plugin.